# "You don't want to..." vs. "You wouldn't want to..."

Tags: conditionals, subjunctive-mood, verb-forms

If I want to tell someone that they shouldn't do something (e.g. buy a computer), should I say:

> You don't want to buy that computer.

or

> You wouldn't want to buy that computer.

I suspect that the latter is the correct choice. But I'm unsure about the first.

Comment: Declaring want someone wants (*don't*) is a bit presumptuous. The subjunctive is more suggestive (*wouldn't*). Both are common, but the former is more aggressive. Even more polite would be *I wouldn't want to buy that computer* (but your needs may vary).

Answer (score 2):

The second option is not appropriate in this situation, as the [conditional](http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/quick-grammar/conditionals-1) is used to talk about things that *would* happen, depending on a condition.

In this case **you wouldn't** indicates that if a certain thing happens, then it *would* be a bad idea to buy the computer. Usually one would extend sentence two, for instance, by saying something along the lines of:

> You wouldn't want to buy that computer **if** *there was a better deal*

Personally I prefer **option 1** as it conveys the meaning that 'it is a bad idea to buy that computer' in **any** situation.

Comment: Conditional is the key.  The second is also good for things that might happen to you, rather than things you would take an an action like "Take a coat, you wouldn't want to catch a cold".